# NSData appendData: UIImageJPEGRepresentation() returns nil

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdata

This has had me scratching for quite some time.

I am preparing a `UIImage` to post as part of a `HTTP request`.  I am doing this with the following code:

```
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                        [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"q%@\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" , key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                        [postData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                        [postData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)]];
                        [postData appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

The problem I am having is that `postData` is `null` after running these lines.

Using `NSLog`  I found out that `[postData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)]];` is the line which is causing this to happen.  I then went on to see if the image was a the problem.  `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)` outputs a mass of data to the console and adding image to a `UIImageView` shows the .jpg I was expecting.

I am absolutely bamboozled. Please help >.<
S

**EDIT**

After a bit of a debacle below I have realised that it is definitely posting the image
.

```
NSLog(@"postData = %@",[postData length]);
```

shows 280861 (bytes?)  but a PHP file with `<?php print_r($_FILES); ?>` returns Array `{}`.

Comment: How are you creating the `postData` instance?

Comment: NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString*post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&json=%@", jsonString];
                NSMutableData *postData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO]];
         
                        UIImage *image = xxxxx

Comment: Just noticed that that is ASCII and the rest UTF8.  I changed this and no improvement

Comment: Just for the experiment: Try UIImagePNGRepresentation instead.

Comment: I had already tried this, same result :(

Comment: Well, you don't need to do dataWithData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with:

```
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\";\r\nfilename=\"%@.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n", key,key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

The first newline after my already included data seems to have resolved this

Answer (score 1):

1. `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)` returns a NSData object that can't be turned into a NSString. A jpeg does not consist of valid characters. And arbitrary data can't be converted to a valid string.
2. Even if `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)` returns nil, the `[NSData dataWithData:]` call makes sure that the data you append to postData is not nil. `[NSData dataWithData:nil];` returns an empty NSData instance, not nil.
3. Regarding your answer. nil is not a valid string encoding. The compiler should show a warning and you should see a warning in the console "Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.".

You can't convert `postData` back into a NSString. If you want to check that the image is part of the NSData object you could look at the length of postData.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification.  I am still having problems with this script though.  I have a PHP script which simply does `<?php print_r($_FILES) ?>` which returns an empty array.  This means that the data is still not being posted correctly.  I will post my full code in the OP

Answer (score 0):

How did you tell `postData` was null? Please note that you can't convert it to UTF8 string using some category/extension as below.

`extension NSData {
    func to_string(encoding:UInt = NSUTF8StringEncoding) -> String? {
        return NSString(data:self, encoding:encoding) as? String
    }
}`